# How to edit docx field contents with Java?

Tags: java, ms-word, docx

I have a .docx template with fields defined in it.  I need to take data inputted by a user in a web-service and insert it into those fields using Java.

My team and I have been researching this for most of the day, and we have been unable to find a straightforward solution to this.

Is there a way to do this relatively easily?

Thanks.

EDIT:

- After pressing alt+F9, all of the fields display like this: `{ FORMTEXT }`
- POI doesn't seem to have sufficient support to do this.
- I was unable to successfully set up the Open Office SDK in Windows XP because I couldn't fulfill all of its dependencies.
- docx4j may work, but MailMerger in it is currently not filling the fields in with the given data.
- If I extract the docx and open the word/document.xml file, this is what the XML around one field looks like: http://pastebin.com/uXBtz7X5  (search for FieldName and FieldValue to see where these are defined)

Comment: Have you tried using Apache POI - http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: It seems that it has basic support for reading and writing docx files, but I don't see a way to directly access the fields contained within the docx file in order to edit them/insert data into them.  Is this possible?

Comment: In my opinion try Open office libraries.

Comment: Any specific libraries you know of that might work for this?

Comment: How were the fields added to the document?  What kind of field is it?  In order to say how to use POI, we need to know what kind of objects are in your document.

Comment: I'm not sure.  The document was supplied to me and was originally protected.  Now when I double click one of the text fields I get a properties box with the title: "Text Form Field Options" or "Check Box Form Field Options" for a check box.

Comment: Ok, so I just saw somewhere to press alt+F9 to see fields, and all of them look like this after pressing alt+F9: `{ FORMTEXT }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Docx4j which you can use to update fields in docx documents there is also and example

[fieldupdater example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/fields/FieldUpdater.java)

Comment: Fieldupdater may have worked, I mostly tried MailMerger as recommended in another answer.  As I mentioned in my answer though, this functionality ended up be non-critical and was scrapped from the project.  Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 3):

**Disclosure: my company sponsors docx4j**

Have a look at [MailMerger](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/fields/merge/MailMerger.java); see the main method at the bottom.

For fields of other types, you can try the more generic field support.

Comment: I'm trying to use MailMerger, and it looks to be opening and saving the file properly; however, it is not injecting the desired data into the fields.  I'm doing the following for a field named `Text14` for which I am attempting to inject the text `Test14`: `map.put( new DataFieldName("Text14"), "Test14");`   Is this proper usage?

Comment: The fields appear to be: `{ FORMTEXT }` after pressing alt+F9

Comment: MailMerger is for fields of type MERGEFIELD.  "FORMTEXT" fields are supposed to have an ffData child, which might contain your variable name (unzip the docx and have a look in document.xml). If it does, you should be able to adapt the MailMerger code.

Comment: I just tried adding some `MERGEFIELD` type fields, and it still isn't inserting any text into them.

Comment: I just tried creating a new document and adding two mergefields, one mapped and one unmapped (because I'm sure what that means) via Insert => Quick Parts => Field... => MergeField, in a docx on Word 2007. I ran the MailMerge on this document, and nothing happened.

Comment: To help you with this, you'll need to provide more details (ie provide the XML that you are running MailMerger on).  Either post a new question here (use docx4j tag), or in the docx4j forums.

Answer (score 0):

The docx format is a zip file, with XML and other files inside. You may be able to edit the XML files using standard XML tools.

Comment: I realize this, but how would I go about filling out the actual `{ FORMFIELD }` fields that are defined in the .docx file?

Comment: Try saving 2 versions of the document, one with the form fields unfilled, and the other with them filled. Then see what changes, and perhaps you'd be able to do the same programatically. You probably already know this, but the document text is inside the `word` folder, in `document.xml`.

Comment: Yep, I found the document.xml file.  I've tried looking through it, but to edit it manually with Java seems like it would be huge pain and be pretty inefficient.

Comment: I updated the OP with a pastebin link showing a portion of the document.xml where a field is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Docmosis and JODReports might help you - they are Java libraries for producing documents / populating templates in several formats.  Docmosis can work with DocX and since they are based on the same techologies JODReports probably can too.  I don't know if the particular {FORMTEXT} field is going to work, but Docmosis can work with plain-text files or Word's merge fields which look like {MERGEFIELD} when you press ALT-F9.